# Content not shifting up when Diji TitlePane collapsed

Tags: dojo, dijit.form, dijit.layout

Quite simple really.

I have two ContentPanes that I load content into dynamically. The content I load dynamically contains TitlePanes. When I collapse these TitlePanes the content below the TitlePane does not shift up.

*(you may ask why I don't load the content into ContentPanes INSIDE the TitlePanes. The reason I don't do that is because the TitlePanes won't expand to cover the dynamic content)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154103/how-to-resize-dijit-contentpane-height-according-to-dynamically-loaded-content-si). All you need to do apperently is add `doLayout="false`

`<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="..." splitter="false" doLayout="false"></div>`